# Should a BSTR From a CString::AllocSysString() be freed?

Tags: c++

```
/* Code Snippet */
CString pString;
pString.Format("LoginWhite : %s",IP.GetString());
BSTR szRuleFind = pString.AllocSysString();
// Check for Existing Rule
HRESULT hr = pRules->Item(szRuleFind,&pFind);
SysFreeString(szRuleFind);
```

Would the "Freeing" of the BSTR be done like this or would the COM Object[INetFwRules* in this case] do so when you `::Release()` the Object?

Comment: you'll need to check the documentation for `pRules->Item` for what it does with the passed string, unless it explicitly states that it'll free the string then it wont

Comment: Yes, you're better off using's [ATL::CComBSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccombstr-class?view=msvc-170) it has RAII behavior and will do this for you.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you for the Reply! I Asked since the MSDN documentation didn't show anything on what it does to the BSTR.

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer You really do give concise answers, you've helped me a lot since yesterday. Thanks Again! I'll Read the documentation you've just sent and see if my VS2008 SP1 have it.

Comment: This is not normally documented since it subject to the Principle of Least Astonishment.  The caller may well want to use the string for other purposes, like calling the function again or storing the result along with the string in a collection object.  The caller is the "owner", the callee has no business pulling the rug.  The only exception to that principle is when the string is passed by reference and the callee needs to call SysAllocString.  If the pointed-to string is not NULL then the pointer would be lost, so the callee must call SysFreeString on the old string.